# Same uninstall registry for all Win OS?

Tags: registry, installation, registrykey, wow64

I check is my program is installed in registry using these paths:

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

,

```
SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

But I am not sure if these paths work for all windows operating systems newer than Win XP.

Comment: I see the question mark but not the question?

Comment: it should work for all windows versions.